# Express app.put / app.post outputs null values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm really new to node/express/mongoDB coding, and I have a slight problem with adding/updating values into mongoDB via node/express.

```
app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    let data = {
        first_value: req.body.first_value,
        second_value: req.body.second_value,
    };
    dbase.collection("testDB").insertOne(data, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        res.send('data added successfully');
    });
});

app.put('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    var id = { _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id) };
    dbase.collection("testDB").updateOne({ _id: id }, {
        $set: {
            first_value: req.body.first_value
            second_value: req.body.second_value,
        }
    }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.send('data updated sucessfully');
    });
});
```

app.put does not alter the values in DB, and app.post only adds "null" into every section of the new entry when I'm trying them with Postman. When I add new values with html form, the data is added correctly.

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: when a backend api works from UI, probably should work with postman with correct request, Did you try debugging code by adding few console.log's to print the values(by this you would know of any improper data issues, also do you mean by null in all fields)? Plus did you try to inspect the request from html page ?

Answer (score 0):

For app.post , can you provide me a screen shot of the way you are entering data  and in which format e.g. , application/raw , application/x-www-form-urlencoded etc .

For `app.put` you need to correct the following things . The corrected code is as below ,

```
app.put('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    var id = { _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id) };
    dbase.collection("testDB").updateOne( id , { // put "id" instead of "{ _id: id }"
        $set: {
            first_value: req.body.first_value
            second_value: req.body.second_value,
        }
    }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.send('data updated sucessfully');
    });
});
```

Hope you can get the point and this works for you .

Answer (score 0):

```
app.put('/:title', (req, res) => {
  const title = req.params.title;
  const index = data.findIndex(obj => obj.title === title);
  if (index !== -1) {
    data[index] = req.body;
    res.send(`Object with title ${title} updated`);
  } else {
    res.send(`Object with title ${title} not found`);
  }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).